# Quick HTML IMG solution

Tags: html

I'm looking for a Quick/Dirty HTML-solution for a one-time problem

I have a lot of images I want to add to a HTML-page, and have them resized to predefined sizes.

For that I at first used :

```
<img src="1980_cover.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:200px;">
<img src="1981_cover.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:200px;">
```

Looks how I want it, but seems I can't add some text over it

So I tried :

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="128px" height="200px" background="1980_cover.jpg" valign="bottom"><font size="+1" color="black">1980</font></td>
    <td width="128px" height="200px" background="1981_cover.jpg" valign="bottom"><font size="+1" color="black">1981</font></td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem I have now, and can't find a solution is how to resize the images instead of cropping them.

As said, I just need this once, so it only should do what's needed, **as simple as possible, legacy or bad HTML-coding isn't an issue for me**

Anyone ?

Comment: google an image resizer online

Comment: "but seems I can't add some text over it" -- did you mean add a div as an overlay for text on it?

Comment: "did you mean add a div as an overlay for text on it?" As in the second example, some text on top of the background

Comment: @user1566399 Did you try my provided answer?

Comment: @user1566399 Would be nice to mark the answer as correct, so that others see your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to achieve this with your second attempt, you can use CSS3 background-size property like so:

```
background-size: 128px 200px;
```

You can use this property together with your background image in an HTML inline style tag.